# Understanding why the integral test is applicable in $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Here is the statement of the integral test and question (e) that I want to solve:

[image]

**My questions are:**

1- I know that here $f(x) = \frac{\ln x}{x^2} $ as this is a question of MATH subject GRE test and $\log n$ means $\ln n.$ But I do not know why my function is positive? as at $x=1$ I know that my function is equal 0.

2- why my function is monotonically decreasing? I know that I should calculate $\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}$ and it should be greater than 1 or checking the difference between $a_{n}$ and $a_{n+1}$ but the formula I get does not give me any inference.

Could anyone help me in answering those questions, please?

I calculated the improper integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln x}{x^2} $ and I got that it converges to 1. I have no problem in that step.

Comment: You care about eventual behavior. Sure, $\ln(x)/x^2$ isn't positive at $x=1$. Sure, it's increasing on $(1,1.649)$; but afterwards it's decreasing. Apply the integral test on $[2,\infty)$.

Comment: It doesn't need to be positive everywhere in the interval $[1,+\infty);$ it only needs to be the case that for some $c>0,$ for all $x>c,$ $f(x)>0. \qquad$

Comment: They are tricking you, actually it is also sufficient for function that decrease later. Yes (e) is converging. Take the integral test with a "grain of salt". :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(n)=2n \frac{\frac{1}{2} - \ln(n)}{n^4} < 0 $ for $n\ge 2 $
So, $f(n)$ monotone decreasing for $n\ge 2 $ .
And, take $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n^2} $, take out the first term.

Answer (score 2):

The integrand just has to be *eventually* decreasing. The behavior of the first two (or 202) terms is irrelevant.

You can check $\ln(x)/x^{2}$ has negative derivative for large enough $x$, so the function is decreasing for large enough $x$.